# No need of selecting Distribution certificate manually?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am going to upload my first App to App Store.
I am selecting Automatically manage signing option.If I do so,do I have to manually select the release Distribution certificate and Provisioning Profile for distribution in Project and Targets? 
With out selecting Distribution certificate manually when i validate the project, validation is Successful.Is it ok to upload to AppStore? 
 Hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is through Xcode. If automatic signing is enabled, Xcode will create and manage certificates, signing identities, and handle device registration for you.

[image]

For more help [go here](https://blog.instabug.com/2017/08/how-to-submit-app-to-app-store/)

Answer (score 0):

When you release to AppStore Xcode will redo codesign of the bundle and use your team Signing Identity.

'Code Signing Identity' in Release can't be your Developer ID.

I suggest you to revert all the manual edits in the 'Build Settings' (the one in bold), go in 'General' and under signing select 'Automatically ...'. This will manage all the certificates and codesign for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks...Is there any way to revert all the manual edits and set default value in xcode? because i am not sure of my changes

Comment: Select the value and hit 'backspace' key on keyboard